# PHP: base64 image string to image reference

Tags: php, base64, jpeg

How do I take an base64 string image and covert it to a image reference.  The base64 string is sent via ajax.  I'm not sure if image reference is the correct terminology so I'll provide an example.

```
#original method
$newImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($oImg);

#new method
$newImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($base64String);  //THIS IS NOT CORRECT
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = base64_decode($base64String);

$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

In this example, `imagecreatefromstring()` doesn't refer to an actual string of letters in the PHP sense, but rather a blob of data/bytes.

Comment: With this method, I won't need to check its file format(jpg, png, gif). It'll create the image as long as it's a supported format.  Then I can save it in any format, right?

Comment: Yes, `imagecreatefromstring()` will automatically detect the type of image file from those supported on your machine: GIF, JPEG, PNG, WBMP, GD2, etc.